# How to display the pandas data frame that is styled in spyder or Jupyter and in html webpage

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, dataframe, jinja2

I have a data frame to which I have applied styling options to highlight data.
when I print the data frame in spyder I see this:

```
<pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object at 0x11a291160>
```

And when I try to display in html webpage as:

```
return render_template('device.html', device=device)

#device.html

{{device.to_html | safe}}
```

This says 'pandas.io.formats.style.Styler object' has no attribute 'to_html'
and if I try to display like this:

```
 {{device | safe}}
```

Its empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call [render](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.0/generated/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.render.html#pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.render) on your Styler object so that it renders html. So your jinja template should look like this:

```
{{device.render | safe}}
```

DataFrame objects have [to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method.

Comment: Dataframe objects do have to_html method but styler objects don't have. I'll try render